# PHP 8 Session cache limiter error but not with other versions of php

Tags: php, session, server

Since I upgraded to PHP 8, I get this error:
*session_start(): Session cache limiter cannot be sent after headers have already sent...*

I have had this error for several months and it only appears from time to time :

- When I am inactive for too long the site
- When I post a form
- When I download a video that is too heavy

What has been done :

- I did a lot of research and it was impossible for me to find the solution.
- The error does not appear in PHP 7.4.
- There is no code that is placed before the session_start().
- The session.save_path has been redefined.
- IDE with UTF-8 without BOM.

The code :

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'core/Config.php';

Config::autoloader();

$template = new Template();

?>
```

Comment: This particular error message does not appear to give a hint, _where_ the output started. If you place a `header` call before the session_start - can be something meaningless such as `header('x-foo: bar');` - then you should get an error message that contains `(output started at file:linenumber)` - try and see if that gives you anything more to go by.

Comment: Funny. The "output started" hint was removed in PHP/7.2 ([fiddle](https://3v4l.org/ufM0o)).